# SmartGit: Graph looks confusing

Tags: git, smartgit

After creating and merging some branches of my new project it looks like this:

[image]

This it hard to understand and does not give an overview as helpful as it could be. Because two merge commits are displayed as vertical-only lines and the overall structure is not very intuitively. In some intermediate states it looked even worse with several overlapping lines.
I know this graph changes depending on which branch is currently checked out but this is not getting much better. Is there any way to parameterize the graph generation for example to let it use more layers (one for each branch)?

In the end I would like to have it like this:

[image]

This is how Sourcetree shows the same graph. I don't want to use Sourcetree, but I really prefer how this graph looks.

Comment: The main difference I see is that your HEAD branch (black) immediately moves to the right. This is most likely caused by SmartGit giving priority to the second commit (which has a ref, too) according to a configurable scheme. Are you using Git-Flow and what are the full names of the "origi..." branches?

Comment: do you have a `View > Group Commits by Branch` entry in your menu ? Can you either un-check it, or choose an option which would say "order commits by date" ?